# $t^{\frac{1}{t-1}}$ and $t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$ need to be integers

Tags: number-theory

$t^{\frac{1}{t-1}}$ and $t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$ need to be integers. Is this only for $t = 2$ and $t = \frac{1}{2}$ true? $t$ can be any positive real number

Could anyone give me a hint how to prove it, if it's true?

Comment: Is $t$ an integer, or an arbitrary positive real number?

Comment: t can be any positive real number

Comment: That makes it a little more difficult. Still, let $m = t^{t/(t-1)}$ and $n = t^{1/(t-1)}$. Then $t = \frac{m}{n}$. So $n^{\frac{m-n}{n}}$ is rational.

Answer (score 0):

The function $t^{1 \over t-1}$ is decreasing yet larger than $1$. Thus, the only integer values it can obtain are when $t\le2$. Conversely, $t^{t \over t-1}$ is increasing, and is equal to $4$ when $t=2$.

Now you can easily check the remaining possible solutions.

Comment: Okay, so I need to find the $t$'s where $t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$ is $0$,$1$,$2$ or $3$. But how can I solve the equations $0 = t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$, $1 = t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$, $2 = t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$ and $3 = t^{\frac{t}{t-1}}$?